# How to convert an integer to time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have time in hours as shown below

hour:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
```

I would like to have the time like:

```
00:00:00
01:00:00
02:00:00
03:00:00 etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution by using `pandas` and `datetime` python library. I hope it will help you

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
hour = 13
a = pd.to_datetime(hour, format='%H')
converted_time = a.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(converted_time)
```

Output

```
13:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `time` from `datetime`:

```
In [1]: from datetime import time

In [2]: for i in range(4):
   ...:     t = time(i, 0, 0)
   ...:     print(t.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
   ...:

00:00:00
01:00:00
02:00:00
03:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` with its function `strptime`. Used like that :

```py
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.strptime(str(your_int), "%H")
print(t.strftime("%H"))
```

Using the `strptime` is useful, because if your int format change, you can still directly format it to a date, using the different codes available here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-strptime-behavior